# LightSwitch HTML legacy browser support

Tags: cross-browser, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I'd like what browser's version are being supported by LightSwitch HTML. For example, do you know if it supports IE8?

Regards,
Luis

Answer (score 0):

No. Lightswitch HTML clients are built on HTML5 and rely heavily on jquery. While jquery 1.x is supported on IE 6+, IE 8 does not support many of the features of HTML5.

http://caniuse.com/#search=html5

http://jquery.com/browser-support/

https://html5test.com/results/desktop.html